# Cannot print json data from Symfony controller with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs, symfony

I am building a simple app here in order to get some json response from a sqlite database and manipulate the data with Angular. Although i send the response from Symfony i cannot use ng-repeat in Angular . Is there any error in the serialization from Symfony?
The delimiter for Angular is [[  ]]

My Symfony Controller acts as an api

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/users", name="get_users")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $users = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Data')
            ->findAll();
            // $serializedUsers = $this->container->get('serializer')->serialize($users, 'json');
            $serializer = $this->get('serializer');
            $array = $serializer->normalize($users);
        return new JsonResponse($array);
    }
```

My angular controller

```
userApp.controller('UserController',function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('/users').success(function(response){
        $scope.users = response;

    });
});
```

My html view

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
                [[user.id]]
            </div>
```

Comment: What's the result of console.log(response); ?

Comment: What are you getting in your response object? Try doing a `console.log(response)` and see what you're getting. It's possible that either the call to `/users` didn't return successfully or that the response isn't the proper type.